# Simple GET request returns empty

Tags: django

Here's my HTML code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}




<form class="form-horizontal" action="/application/" method="get">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="userid">User ID</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="userid" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="pass">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign in">
            <br>
            <a href="forgot">Forgot password?</a>
            <br>
            <a href="change">Change password?</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>






{% endblock %}
```

Here's my function in my view:

```
def application(request):
    print request.GET
    message=[]
    for key,value in request.GET:
        message.append("%s:%s"%key,value)
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Here no matter what I input, my 'print request.GET' prints a  `<QueryDict: {}>`.

I can't figure out how to debug this. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

none of your inputs have `name` attributes,

`name` attributes are what are used to populate data for GET request.

`<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password">`

The above will show up with key `name` in `request.GET`

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the last message, I suppose you want to render the template instead?

Try [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) instead.